# Ubuntu 14.04.2 partition installing help!

Tags: partitioning, usb, live-usb, usb-drive

I'm trying to install Ubuntu to a partition. Will this allow me to save my changes that i make on the system? I'm really concerned if this would or could mess my laptop up.

Comment: Well, is there anything on your laptop that could get messed up? Your hardware is not at risk, but any data is, if you're uncareful during the installation of Ubuntu and have no backup (which you should have anyway).

Comment: yes i created a system restore. can i just select Install Ubuntu alongside windows 8.1 or should i choose Something else and create my partition that way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the changes are persistent if you install to a partition.

Your laptop can be messed if the partition you install Ubuntu in has any information that you want to use after the install.

Comment: so if i create a new partition and install Ubuntu 14.04.2 on it from my live-usb. how do i install it safely because i've been on 1000 different websites and dont have a clue of what they're talking about. they go off topic and i get lost. can u help me out, like if u know of any video's that will show me how to install Ubuntu 14.04.2 to my partition please tell me... Please!!!

Comment: Check out the answer to this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported